# Apple Pay in an iFrame with verified domains

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments, applepay

TL;DR I want to show Apple Pay in an iFrame, where both domains (iFrame domain and top level domain) are verified with Apple Pay. It's not working. Any hints?

Hello! I'm using Stripe + Apple Pay on `sample.com`. I'm then embedding an iFrame of `sample.com` into `second-website.com`. I have control of both domains and I have successfully verified BOTH domains with Stripe and Apple Pay.

I can clearly see the Apple Pay option `sample.com`. However, when I embed the iFrame of `sample.com` into `second-website.com`, I don't see the Apple Pay option.

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Hello!

TL;DR I want to show Apple Pay in an iFrame, where both domains (iFrame domain and top level domain) are verified with Apple Pay. It's not working. Any hints?

Hello! I'm using Stripe + Apple Pay on `sample.com`. I'm then embedding an iFrame of `sample.com` into `second-website.com`. I have control of both domains and I have successfully verified BOTH domains with Stripe and Apple Pay.

I can clearly see the Apple Pay option `sample.com`. However, when I embed the iFrame of `sample.com` into `second-website.com`, I don't see the Apple Pay option.

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Probably not supported https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004593/3631795

Answer (score 0):

According to [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=web#web-integration-considerations):

> Using an iframe with Elements: When using an iframe, its origin must match the top-level origin (except for Safari 17 when specifying allow="payment" attribute). Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, host (full domain name), and port (if specified) are the same for both pages.

So the answer is no. Apple Pay will not work in your case.

https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=web#web-integration-considerations